# I can't boot to windows on UEFI MODE ( Triple boot Laptop )

Tags: uefi

I noticed that I can not boot anymore to my Windows 10 on my lenevo G50 .
Note that booting to Windows requires EFI mode and I've installed linux on Legacy mode ( from BIOS Setting )
the order of installations is Windows 10 ( Stock ) > Kubuntu > Korora

Notice that I've on my laptop both of kubuntu 15 (32 bits) & korora 22 next to windows 10
When I boot into legacy mode Hard drive is shown okay and boots to Grub ( So i can use my Kubuntu 15.10 x86 or korora 22 normally without problems )
but if I choose Windows 10 from grub menu it shows me a black screen with Windows boot error 0xc0000225
and If I swhitch into the UEFI Mode from Bios Setting , the hard drive disapears from boot menu ( I get only network IPV4 boot or something like that )

I've tried to search on google for the 0xc0000225 error and tried all the methodes to fix it and they didn't work , and when I try to do a new installation with a Windows  7/8/10 DVD when the pc reboots after installation i get nothing ( the same error from Grub boot and no hard drive in EFI Mode )

When I Tried Ubuntu Live USB boot iso to perform an automatic boot repair it says : 
"You have installed on sda10 a Linux version which is not EFI-Compatible. You may want to install a 64-bit Linux instead"

Answer (score 1):

> Note that booting to Windows requires EFI mode and I've installed linux on Legacy mode

This was a mistake. Furthermore....

> When I Tried Ubuntu Live USB boot iso to perform an automatic boot repair it says : "You have installed on sda10 a Linux version which is not EFI-Compatible. You may want to install a 64-bit Linux instead"

This error message suggests that you've installed a 32-bit version of Ubuntu. If so, and if you have a 64-bit EFI and 64-bit version of Windows, your best bet is to do as the message suggests: Install a 64-bit version of Ubuntu. Furthermore, you should do so in EFI mode. (*Disable* the CSM, aka legacy-mode support, in your firmware.)

To better understand why a mixed-mode setup is likely to be troublesome, see [my Web page on the subject.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) In brief, most EFIs make switching between modes awkward. Enabling the CSM can also effectively randomize your mode of booting from external media, which makes the creation of incompatible installations far too likely.